# Embed custom tab bar controller after loginVC programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am working without Storyboards.
After the successful login, I'd like to add a tabBar into my viewControllers.
I created another viewController called tabBar controller with the code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Create Tab one
    let tabOne = Home()
    let tabOneBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Collection", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "matchTabIcon"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "matchTabIconSelected"))
    tabOne.tabBarItem = tabOneBarItem
    // Create Tab two
    let tabTwo = ScoutingVC()
    let tabTwoBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Scouting", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "scouting"), selectedImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "scoutingSelected"))
    tabTwo.tabBarItem = tabTwoBarItem2
    self.viewControllers = [tabOne, tabTwo]
}
// UITabBarControllerDelegate method
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("Selected \(viewController.title!)")
}
```

}

**What is the correct way to add this to all of my VCs?**

I tried

```
self.vc.addSubView(tabBarController)
```

and also to create a func() in the first VC (index: 0), but either the tabBar is not there, or if there, doesn't switch between viewControllers.

```
func showTabBarController() {
    // Create Tab one
    let home = Home()
    let homeTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Collection", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "matchTabIcon"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "matchTabIconSelected"))
    home.tabBarItem = homeTabBarItem
    let navHome = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: home)
    // Create Tab two
    let scouting = ScoutingVC()
    let scoutingTabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Scouting", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "scouting"), selectedImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "scoutingSelected"))
    scouting.tabBarItem = scoutingTabBarItem
    let navScouting = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: scouting)
    //showTabBar
    tabBarCnt.viewControllers = [navHome, navScouting]
    self.view.addSubview(tabBarCnt.tabBar)
}
```

Comment: Instead of using self.vc.addSubView(tabBarController) use present(TabBarController(), animated: false, completion: nil)

Comment: That's the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I posted as an answer, could you accept it to close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using self.vc.addSubView(tabBarController) use present(TabBarController(), animated: false, completion: nil)